# jQuery controls go loose on application migration to new server

Tags: jquery, windows, hide, show

I have a .Net application previously hosted on Windows Server (2007).  The .Net application uses jQuery and everything worked fine.  Now that I migrated the application to Windows Server (2012) the `hide()` function is no longer working.

I have done all the due diligence like making sure the script tag is well formed and the `src` points to the location of the jQuery library. I have even used a Google hosted library in the process but nothing worked.

From the browser console, I am able to do `$('#xyz').show()` and `$('#xyz').hide()` and it worked. The problem is that once my application is loaded on the browser the page loads find but once I click on any control (like the radio button) all the controls that are supposed to be hidden goes loose all at once.

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? We can't really help you without seeing either your code, nor any details of errors you receive. Simply stating 'it doesn't work' helps no one, least of all you.

Comment: Rory is right, we need more information to be any help to you. Do you have a hosted anywhere that is accessible to us or can you go to jsfiddle.net and give us an example? Migrating to a new servers should have no affect on jquery but the generated html could differ bases on the framework you are using

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this problem occurs because jQuery (usually) fails after a partial page postback (in ASP.Net). I found suggestions to fixing the problem at http://www.codepal.co.uk/show/JQuery_breaks_after_ASPNET_partial_page_postback#pageload.  The solution that worked for me was to put my jQuery code inside

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function pageLoad()
        { 
          //jQuery code here
        }
    </script>
```

Thanks to Rory and @jnoreiga for attempting to help.